# Is there a way to execute a JavaScript/JQuery function on my html page for a specified amount of time then stop the execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am employing a ripple effect on a background image of a web page. As it sits right now, the effect is present on page load and creates ripples in the background as a user moves the mouse cursor. I am trying to figure out a way to stop the effect after a set amount of time (20s).

I have tried utilizing the `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()`, as well as combining/nesting these into a `setTimeout()`. I reviewed a similar question but attempts at the various solutions did not work.

My most recent attempt was:

```
var animateBackground = setInterval(function() {
    $('body').ripples({
     resolution: 1297,
     dropRadius: 10,
     perturbance: 0.04,
     });
   }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function(){
    clearInterval(animateBackground);
  }, 20000);
```

I am relatively new into web design/coding, and really appreciate any help the community can provide.

Comment: A quick housekeeping note: please don't post an answer as part of the question text; that makes things potentially confusing for future users.  You can instead post your own separate answer (even on your own question) to supplement or improve on existing answers.

Comment: Roger that, added as an answer as suggested. I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the correct syntax for stopping a setInterval.

But it looks like that `ripples` plugin you're using doesn't *need* to be set on an interval; it runs continuously until you call `$(selector).ripples('pause')` or `$(selector).ripples('destroy')`.

https://github.com/sirxemic/jquery.ripples

So all you would need is

```
$('body').ripples({
   resolution: 1297,
   dropRadius: 10,
   perturbance: 0.04,
});
setTimeout(function(){
  $('body').ripples('pause') // or 'destroy', or 'hide'
}, 20000);
```

Comment: Very good catch, and shame on me for trying to solve it while forgetting to double check usage documentation. I am marking this as answered, thank you for the swift response!

Comment: No worries, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

This question has been successfully answered, and I provide the following update for clarity in the future if this question gets revisited:

In case anyone else ends up at this question, I noticed using 
`$('body').ripples('hide')`
works nicely as well, and instead of freezing the play state with whatever ripples are still present, it clears the effect from the screen and returns the background to a static image.

Here is the final version of the working script.

```
<script>
    $('body').ripples({
     resolution: 1297,
     dropRadius: 10,
     perturbance: 0.04,
     });

  setTimeout(function(){
    $('body').ripples('hide');
  }, 20000);
 </script>
```